# JS library seems to be not loaded in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, qr-code

I tried to add a library (static resource) to scan a QR code in a lightning web component but I get an error message

> Html5QrcodeScanner is not defined.

This is what I do:

```js
import html5_qrcode from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/html5_qrcode';
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

connectedCallback() {
    Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, html5_qrcode)
    ])
    .then(() => {
        var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner( "reader", { fps: 100, qrbox: 250 });
        html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess);
        showToastSuccess('Library loaded');
    })
    .catch(error => {
        showToastError(error.message);
    });
}
```

The library works fine with a simple HTML page.

I tried by disabling the locker service but nothing changed so the locker service is not the origin of the problem.

Do you know what is wrong please?

Here is a link to an article which deals about the library: https://blog.minhazav.dev/research/html5-qrcode

Thanks

Comment: it'll be something wrong with the url. Check the console and see if it is showing a 404 error. Then try out a different url syntax until you get the right one.

Comment: You mean the URL to import the JS library (static resource)?

Comment: Yes, you'll see the failed request in the console (if it failed).

Comment: I have no log in the debug console. :(

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that will make this lib to not work:

- Based on element id which is not supported in LWC context
- Not Locker Service compatible as far I can tell (and can't be disabled in LWC, as far as I know)
- Using the minified version is [deprecated](https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode/tree/master/minified)

I would advise to use the [Salesforce library](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_lightning_barcodescanner) which is embedded / supported and probably working in mobile context.

In the browser context I would suggest:

- Fork the library to make additional adjustments like:

  - Don't use elementId but element directly and make checks for element validity before use to avoid any errors
  - Add wrapper to allow loading into LWC context `(function (window) { libContent })(window)` should work
- Use another library

  - https://www.npmjs.com/package/qr-code-scanner

Comment: I think the response is because it is based on element id and it is not supported in LWC context. :(

The BarScodeScanner doesn't work because we use a web browser and it is not supported.

Comment: I updated my answer for browser context.

Answer (score 0):

Check the static resource structure. Is it a js file or is it a zip? If js file, try adding ".js" at the end like `loadScript(this, html5_qrcode + '.js')`. See if that resolves the issue. You can monitor your resource loading under network tab of browser dev tools.

Comment: The static resource is well loaded without the "+ '.js'" becquse I have an error if I add it.

But my error when it is loaded is "HtmlQrcodeScanner is not defined".

To resume, the js library is loaded but Salesforce is unable to see objects.